# Why am I getting a 'not found' error for a subdirectory store in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am running Magento CE 1.7.0.2 and am trying to set up a second store using the 'subdirectory method' described here: http://www.crucialwebhost.com/blog/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/

When I try to navigate to my new storefront it gives me this error:

"[my root directory]/[my new store's subdirectory]/app/Mage.php was not found"

Everything else in the backend of Magento seems to be setup fine - can anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After you copy the index.php to the sub directory, you would need to change the index.php in the subdirectory to point it to the app/Mage.php.

Find the following in the subdirectory index.php

`$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';`

and replace it with

`$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';`

For completeness you should do the same thing for the $compilerConfig variable

`$compilerConfig = '../includes/config.php';`